# How to define a variable that conforms to a trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to instantiate a variable that I will pass into a function that takes a `T: Write`. It would be defined as follows:

```
let outputFile = match matches.opt_str("o") {
    Some(fileName) => File::create(fileName).expect("could not open output file"),
    None => std::io::stdout()
};
```

Currently, the compiler will complain about non-matching types in arms (`File` vs. `Stdout`). All I want is to declare `outputFile` as something I can call any method from the `Write` trait on and nothing else.

Does Rust allow me to do this or do I have to bring this entire `match` expression as a parameter to be passed into that function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to return one of two (or more) separate types that implement a trait, then you need to return a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/trait-objects.html).

In this case you need the return value to own the object (since otherwise the `File` would be destroyed before the end of the `match`), so it it makes sense to use `Box<dyn Write>`.  Trait objects such as `&Write` and `Box<dyn Write>` are "fat" pointers, which include both a pointer to the struct (`File` or `Stdout` in this case) as well as a pointer to a vtable which describes how to implement `Write`.  Importantly, `Box<dyn Write>` and `&Write` automatically implement `Write`.

Here's a working version ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15fe776559c265dd510ad79e12b4d071&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn get_writer(f: Option<&str>) -> Box<dyn Write> {
    match f {
        Some(file_name) => Box::new(File::create(file_name).expect("could not open output file")),
        None => Box::new(std::io::stdout()),
    }
}
```

I've made a few changes from your code:

- Added the `Box<dyn Write>` return value (without a function you may need to have `let outputFile: Box<dyn Write> = ...`; without having the type defined somewhere the compiler won't be able to infer that it needs to coerce the two types to the common `Box<dyn Write>`.  Once the compiler knows that it needs `Box<dyn Write>`, it can *coerce* a `Box<File>` to `Box<dyn Write>`.
- Boxed the two results.
- Renamed `fileName` to `file_name` to match Rust conventions (and silence the warning).